# Debugging android app on phone against local dev server (Google Endpoints) fails to connect with router

Tags: android, google-app-engine, debugging, google-cloud-endpoints

I've an android app installed on my phone (debug build) and a local dev server. The app is using GAE Endpoints. I've updated the API builder by adding

```
b.setRootUrl("http://[myIP]:8080/_ah/api");
```

However, the app cannot connect. I've verified the dev server is up and running.

As a test, I tped

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

in by browser and I get the api explorer, etc.
However, if I do

```
http://[myIP]:8080/
```

I get "this webpage is not available". So clearly that must be the root cause.
The way I get my IP address is by running `ipconfig` in a `cmd`.

I tried turning off my firewall but that didn't make any difference.

Any and all help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. i have a router so need to go into my router settings and add a 'virtual server' (that feature may be called something else for your router) redirecting from my ROUTER ip address (not what you get from ipconfig), and a port (whatever you want, need to use it in the setRootUrl), to my server address (what you DO get from ipconfig) and the local dev server port (typically 8080)
2. when i start my server in Android Studio i need to specify address 0.0.0.0, can be easily done in Android Stuiod by editing the run config (don't forget to restart it after that change)
3. update b.setRootUrl to point to the router ip address from 1. and the port you picked in 1. as well (don't forget to rerun your app after the update which will re-install it on your phone)
4. disable firewall -- however that's unsafe so instead i've created a special rule for this connection. (when setting inbound rules, a big gotcha is that there are usually predefined rules to block ALL connections from Java SDK/JRE for all installed versions on your system which will take precedence. You would need to modify those: I wouldn't advise disabling the whole rule, but you can modify to specific ports as such Ports: 1-[your server port-1], [your server port + 1, 65535].

The combination of those four works for me. Hope this helps someone!